# R - Combine two mice mids objects when data frames have different columns

Tags: r, rbind, imputation, r-mice

I'm using the mice package on two different but related data frames.
While the large majority of the variables are the same for both data frames, a small number of variables are unique to each data frame and the imputation happens for both data frames separately (they have slightly different imputation models/ predictor matrices, etc.).

In the end, I would like to combine the two resulting mids objects,
but as the columns differ, the standard procedure via rbind(actually method rbind.mids is called) does not work.

Is there an easy way around this?
Two alternative approaches I could think of:

1. Combine the two dfs one time before imputation via `dplyr::bind_rows` and split them again. Now each data frame has all columns and rbind() would work after the imputations. However, that would also require defining the predictor matrix and method section again for both data frames to tell mice to ignore the new columns.
2. Use the `mice::complete(imp_df, "long", include = TRUE)` function on both mids objects, combine the resulting data frames, and use `mice::as.mids()` to convert them back into a single mids object. But I'm not sure if that would work or mess something else up, e.g.

Here is some example data to illustrate the issue

```
library(mice)
data("nhanes2") # load test data from mice package

# make test_df 1
df_1 <- nhanes2[1:14,c(1,2,3)]

# make test_df 2
df_2 <- nhanes2[15:25, c(1,2,4)]

# quick and dirty imputation for test purpose

test_imp1 <- mice(df_1)
test_imp2 <- mice(df_2)

rbind(test_imp1, test_imp2)


Error in rbind.mids.mids(x, y, call = call) : 
  datasets have different variable names
```

Answer (score 0):

The recommended workflow is to use the `blocks` argument, see the documentation on https://amices.org/mice/reference/mice and background info in the FIMD book https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/mice-extensions.html.

> "The main algorithm iterates over blocks. A block is simply a collection of variables. In the common MICE algorithm each block was equivalent to one variable, which - of course - is the default; The `blocks` argument allows mixing univariate imputation method multivariate imputation methods. The `blocks` feature bridges two seemingly disparate approaches, joint modeling and fully conditional specification, into one framework"

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34881651)